# Time-Series analysis with small data set, but long sequences

Tags: classification, time-series, sequence

I'm working on a time-series classification problem. There are 3 classes. Dataset consists of 6 sequences from each class (total 18 sequences). Each sequence is 19,000 in length. What are some time-series classification approaches I can look into?

Comment: if the long sequences contain enough information in the length to distinguish the classes then any seuqence classification model may work (eg LSTM)

Comment: @NikosM. What would be an appropriate way to verify if the sequences contain enough information? For example, say I have sensor bootup data (voltage) from three different types of sensors. The sequences look very similar but there are differences.

Comment: Only way to try and use them and maybe see the time correlations of each sequence with each other in the same class vs with other classes. This could give you a hint